# Why Apache IoTDB reported “can't allow more query tasks” when resources are not full?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently using Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0 and found a problem. When I tried to use `"show queries" command, an error message appears: "Msg: 301: The system can't allow more query tasks."`

I checked the computing resources and seems like it is not full. Right know I can only restart IoTDB to solve this error. Anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is already fixed in the newest version appealed today. You can update to Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.1 in github and see if this problem is solved.